# How do I find the placement of the first instance that the arrays string turns from A to D?

Tags: javascript

This is what I tried below but I can't figure this one out?

I tried several different approaches and seems like I'm missing a small piece of code to figure it out. I was thinking maybe to us If and break when it doesn't equal A and equals D but then how would I count in the array when this happened?

```
const testing = [`aTest`, ` aFun`, `aYay`, `      dFun  `, ,];

let firstLetterChangeAToD;
let firstLetter;
let testingArrayWord;
let largestWord;

for (let i = 0; i <= Object.keys(testing).length; i++) {
    testingArrayWord = testing[`${i}`].trim();
    firstLetter = testingArrayWord.charAt(0);
    console.log(firstLetter);
}
```

Comment: Replace ``testing[`${i}`]`` with `testing[i]`.

Comment: Replace `Object.keys(testing).length` with `testing.length`.

Comment: Replace `testingArrayWord.charAt(0)` with `testingArrayWord[0]`.

Comment: Replace `console.log(firstLetter);` with `if (firstLetter === "d") { console.log(i); break; }`.

Comment: And if you need `i` after the `for` loop, replace `let i` with `var i`.

Comment: Also replace all `\`` with `"`. When you write text between `\`` the computer will search for JavaScript code inside the string, but in your case, there is nothing to search for.